# Phoenix Elixir Controller Unit Test Repo.get_by cannot pass assertion

Tags: unit-testing, elixir, phoenix-framework

I had this unit test in `post_controller_test.exs`:

```
test "creates resource and redirects when data is valid", %{conn: conn, user: user} do
        conn = post conn, user_post_path(conn, :create, user), post: @valid_attrs
        assert redirected_to(conn) == user_post_path(conn, :index, user)
        assert Repo.get_by(assoc(user, :posts), @valid_attrs)
    end
```

@valid_attrs are simple value of `@valid_attrs %{body: "some content", title: "some content"}`. And my `postcontroller create()` def:

```
def create(conn, %{"post" => post_params}) do
        changeset = 
            conn.assigns[:user]
            |> build_assoc(:posts)
            |> Post.changeset(post_params)

        case Repo.insert(changeset) do
            {:ok, _post} ->
                conn
                |> put_flash(:info, "Post created successfully.")
                |> redirect(to: user_post_path(conn, :index, conn.assigns[:user]))
            {:error, changeset} ->
                render(conn, "new.html", changeset: changeset)
        end
    end
```

Test pass on redirect, but failed on `assert Repo.get_by(assoc(user, :posts), @valid_attrs)`. Message is **expected truthy got nil**. I already have assoc with posts on user model:

```
field :username, :string
        field :email, :string
        field :password_digest, :string

        field :password, :string, virtual: true
        field :password_confirmation, :string, virtual: true
        timestamps

        has_many :posts, Pxblog.Post
    end
```

Can anyone explain why that test cannot pass?

Comment: I don't see the problem on the first glance. Redirect suggests that post has been inserted and `Repo.get_by` result suggests it wasn't. I would put `IO.inspect(Repo.all(Post))` between those two asserts and check what really happened.
Is user in your test persisted in the database? Sometimes for tests you only pass the data. In that case the id might be nil.

Comment: @tkowal: [%Pxblog.Post{__meta__: #Ecto.Schema.Metadata<:loaded>, body: nil, id: 144,
  inserted_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-06-21T13:13:49Z>, title: nil,
  updated_at: #Ecto.DateTime<2016-06-21T13:13:49Z>,
  user: #Ecto.Association.NotLoaded<association :user is not loaded>,
  user_id: 216}]

Comment: So it is inserted, but body and title is nil. I suspect you didn't provide required and optional attrs in your model file. This would cause changeset function to ignore all params.

Comment: @tkowal: you are right, thanks